# EvenQ not working properly on IntegerPart[real number]

Tags: numerics

Something fascinating is happening at the moment.

```
force[[All, 6]]={0.5, 0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, \
0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.8, 0.8, \
0.8, 0.9, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99}
```

Above you will find a table of my numbers. I want to check if the number on `i` th place is even or not! I tried to do that with the following code:

```
i = 2;
EvenQ[IntegerPart[force[[i, 6]]*100]]
Out[164]= False
```

and the output is ok, since the second number in the table is 0.55 which is odd and not even. However, 4th number in the table is also odd, yet not according to mathematica:

```
i = 4;
EvenQ[IntegerPart[force[[i, 6]]*100]]

Out[162]= True
```

Dear god! I am a bit lost what went wrong here and what to do...

Comment: All of them are true since your code would multiply all 0 by 100 and then return 0 as an output. For all of the numbers in your collection force. What do you mean by `force[[All,6]]` ?

Comment: @E.Doroskevic Ok, I see the problem now. So it might make more sense to use `Round[x]` instead of `IntegerPart`, right?

Comment: Your problem is due to finite precision number representation. Take a look at `FullForm[.57*100]`. `Round` will see you right.

Comment: No, @E.Doroskevic misread your code and assumed, you're taking the `IntegerPart` before multiplying by 100. `Round` may make more sense, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are working with floating point numbers.  Welcome to the world of floating point arithmetic!

The computer represents floating point numbers in binary, not decimal.  The actual number stored for `0.57` is not precisely `0.57`, but slightly smaller.  Why?  Because `0.57` cannot be represented *exactly* in binary, just like 1/3 = 0.33333333... cannot be represented exactly in decimal.  `0.33333333` is smaller than `1/3`, right?

Thus `IntegerPart[0.57*100]` is `56` and not `57`.

You can get the exact binary representation using `RealDigits[0.57, 2]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
IntegerPart[0.57*100]
(* 56 *)
0.57*100
(* 57. *)
InputForm@%
(* 56.99999999999999 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input:**

```
(*Where `t` is your list*)  
Flatten[EvenQ @ IntegerPart @ {t[[#]]*100} & /@ Range @ Length @ t, 1]
```

**Output:**

> {True, False, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True,
>   True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True,
>   True, True, True, True, False, True, False}

Comment: But he is having `IntegerPart[x*100]`, not `IntegerPart[x]*100` ...

Comment: @Szabolcs I just realised that I have misread the code. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Too many `[` and `]`! :)  It's too easy to misread all those `[[`s ...

Comment: @Szabolcs I think the above looks better now! :D